# Safari Canvas mouseover detection

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, safari

I am using HTML 5 canvas and trying to get the event coordinates from safari in a mac that is attached to another monitor through HDMI. The event works perfectly fine in chrome, Firefox, IE and safari on windows. It also works fine in safari on mac without the additional monitor.

Currently with the monitor attached the coordinates coming back are incorrect through "mouseover"/"mousemove" event. The event fires in canvas safari when I click on my mouse and drag.

Any help would be appreciated. Been stuck on this for awhile.

```
function writeMessage(canvas, message) {
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    document.getElementById('divSaveMessage').innerHTML = message;

}
function getMousePos1(canvas, evt) {
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    return {
        x: evt.clientX - rect.left,
        y: evt.clientY - rect.top
    };
}
var canvas = document.getElementById('Main_canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var mouseX, mouseY;
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function (evt) {
    var mousePos = getMousePos1(canvas, evt);
    mouseX = mousePos.x;
    mouseY = mousePos.y;
    alert("1")
    var message = 'Mouse position: ' + mousePos.x + ',' + mousePos.y;
    writeMessage(canvas, message);
}, false);
```

Comment: Can't repro Safari 9.0.2